# polynom package with only

Tags: beamer, pause, polynom

I'm using the `polynom` package in my `beamer`. I would like the numbers to appear little by little, one in each frame

```
\begin{frame}{Divisão Automática}
  \begin{alertblock}{a.}
     \polylongdiv[style=D]{x^2 + 12x + 35}{x + 7}
  \end{alertblock}
\end{frame}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se. Instead of posting a code fragment, it's more helpful to include your fragment into a complete compilable document that people can play with. You can edit your question to do that.

Comment: The following question has a `beamer` solution that might be helpful. [What is the best way to animate (with multiframe maybe...) the steps of a long polynomial division like this?](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/550590)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE and *Saudações do Brasil*. Please, always post a Minimum Working Example [MME](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that). Snippets of code are not always self sufficient to reproduce your issue or question.

Answer (score 1):

Using the reference cited by @Alan Munn, ([here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/550601/140133)), and adding your `alertblock` and a `theme`, in this case `\usetheme{Copenhagen}`, the following MWE produces the steps of your polynom division.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Copenhagen}
\usepackage{polynom}
\usepackage{pgffor,calc}

\newlength\boxwidth
\newlength\boxheight

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Divisão Automática}
  \begin{alertblock}{a.}
    \settowidth\boxwidth{\polylongdiv[style=D]{x^2 + 12x + 35}{x + 7}}%
    \settototalheight\boxheight{\polylongdiv[style=D]{x^2 + 12x + 35}{x + 7}}%
    \foreach \i in {1,...,7} {%
      \only<\i>{\parbox[t][\boxheight]{\boxwidth}{\polylongdiv[style=D,stage=\i]{x^2 + 12x + 35}{x + 7}}}%
    }
  \end{alertblock}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Commands `\boxwidth` and `\boxheight` are used to predefine the height of the box, without it, the `alertblock` will not fit the whole expression.

[image]

Comment: @Alan Munn, I'm sorry. I believe we were editing the question at the same time. Your comments were shown to me even before I finish my revision while I was preparing the answer and explanation.